# Validar campo con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Buenas, mi duda es la siguiente. ¿Cómo puedo validar un campo con `Javascript`?

Mi código:

```js
 function escribir_nombre(){
   var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
   if(nombre<10){
       alert("El nombre tiene que tener más de 3 letras");
    }else{
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=nombre;
     }
 }
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="formulario" name="formulario" action="">
    Nombre <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
</form>

    <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="enviar" onclick="escribir_nombre()">
    <div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Y si nos ponemos un poco estrictos, la condición debería ser `< 4` si lo que quiere es que el `alert` anuncie información correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres validar que la longitud sea mayor de 3 deberías comprobar la propiedad length del valor:

```js
function escribir_nombre(){
   var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
   if(nombre.length < 4){
      alert("El nombre tiene que tener más de 3 letras");
   }else{
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=nombre;
   }
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="formulario" name="formulario" action="">
    Nombre <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
</form>

    <button id="enviar" name="enviar" onclick="escribir_nombre()">enviar</button>
    <div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Realmente tu problema está en que estás comparando una cadena con un número por lo que la condición siempre irá a la condición del `else`, ya que siempre será falsa.

Tendrías que obtener la longitud de la cadena para poder compararla (ya que esta última si que será un número), con el atributo `length`.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
function escribir_nombre(){
   var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
   if(nombre.length <10){
       alert("El nombre tiene que tener más de 10 letras");
    }else{
      document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML=nombre;
     }
 }
```

```html
<form method="POST" id="formulario" name="formulario" action="">
    Nombre <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre">
</form>

    <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="enviar" onclick="escribir_nombre()">
    <div id="resultado"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Este fragmento de código te podría servir. La validación esta hecho con la java-script y la validación nativa de html5.

```js
function condicion(t) {
  var field = t;
  if (t.value.length <= 5) { //puedes personalizar el mensaje por el que quieras.
    field.setCustomValidity("Debe tener al mas 5 caracteres");
  } else {
    field.setCustomValidity("");
  }
}
function enviar(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("se envio lo valores");
  e.target.reset();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form onsubmit="enviar(event)">
    Nombre <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" onkeyup="condicion(this)" required>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>


  <div id="resultado"></div>
</body>


</html>
```